# Android listview header text disappear on refresh listview

Tags: android, listview, text, header

I have android app with list view and header contains text for list when get the data for first time its ok 
then when get data for second time the same code execute and the text of header is disappear.

**Activity.java**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View header = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, lv, false);
            header.setTag(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "header");
            if (lv.getHeaderViewsCount() > 0) {
                View oldView = lv.findViewWithTag(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "header");
                if (oldView != null) {
                    lv.removeHeaderView(oldView);
                    lv.addHeaderView(header);
                }
            }
                else
                lv.addHeaderView(header);

            TextView tvheader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvheader);
            tvheader.setText("plaplapla...");
```

**Activity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:background="#d9dee2">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/tvheader"
    android:background="#c0c2c4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

any suggestion for that issue

Comment: See here : https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: its stickylistheaders not what i need

Comment: It looks like you are oldview is null. Check the way you get it.I guess thats the problem. Also consider putting block in else, although its optional for a single statement it will increase readability!

Comment: are you getting any errors ?

Comment: @Xenolion no its not null in any way

Comment: @YamenImadNassif
no error ....

Comment: @FarOoOosa  regarding to the solution provided there should be an error or it will be null in best cases :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to get the specific place in findviewbyid :

```
TextView tvheader = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.tvheader);
```

thanks for [Omar Oulabi](https://www.facebook.com/omaroulabi1) from [Ask Syrian Programmers](https://www.facebook.com/groups/ask.syp) Group